# editing very long line, many columns in vim

Tags: vim

I need to edit a file having columns

```
1       0       0       0       1       1       0       0       1       1       1       1       
1       1       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0       0       0             
1       0       0       0       1       1       0       0       1       1       1       1       
1       1       0       1       0       0       0       1       0       0 

      0       0
```

it is a portion of file.

what I want is to add some comments on top of it, and then after every two line add a label e.g:

```
Z A B C D E F
MMSSSS
#A
1       0       0       0       1                 
1       1       0       1       0                
#B
1       0       0       0       1       
1       1       0       1       0
```

how can I do it in vim
as I have 400 columns's line and when I open vim each row is spread accross many lines of screen.

Answer (score 5):

I understand your question as your long lines being wrapped around and you can't easily see where the two lines for the comments start and end. There are various options: 1) activate line numbers with `:set nu`, or 2) prevent wrapping by `:set nowrap`. What is preferable depends on whether you want to see the whole lines without scrolling or not.